# No targets specified and no makefile found

Tags: objective-c, makefile

I have a make file that contains this code:

```
all: main.o Etudiant.o
    gcc -lobjc -o program main.o Etudiant.o
main.o:main.m Etudiant.h
    gcc -c main.m
Etudiant.o:Etudiant.m Etudiant.h
    gcc -c Etudiant.m
```

When I write this in the shell command:

```
$make
```

I got this:

```
make: **** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you running the make command in the directory where makefile is ?

Comment: ...and is the makefile named "Makefile" (with a capital M)?

Comment: If instead of typing `make`, what do you get when you type `ls -l`?

Comment: i got a long list of my subfolders in which there is the Makefile.m file

Comment: Makefile.m?!?!  That is nonsense unless you have an objective-c source named `Makefile.m` on purpose.

Comment: Make does not know that "Makefile.m" might be a makefile. Try `make -f Makefile.m`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make \*\*\* no targets specified and no makefile found. stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412919/make-no-targets-specified-and-no-makefile-found-stop)

Comment: @tripleee surely it's the other way around? This question is 2 years __older__ than the "duplicate" that you are looking at. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The relative age is a secondary concern, we generally want to collect the best answers in a single question and mark all others as duplicates, and so the amount of work is more important than the age of the individual questions and answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mmm... makefiles.  Whee.

All that whitespace at the beginning of the line.   That has to be tabs.  Or Make will barf up a really obscure error.   Make sure those are tabs and try again.

---

See the button on the left side of the keyboard labeled "tab".   Delete the spaces and hit that once to insert a tab character.

---

Try `make all`.   IIRC (been a few years since I've had to muck with makefiles) most makes will default to `all`, but maybe yours isn't.

Extension doesn't matter.

---

## Holy Heck! We are all Extra Dense(@bbum mostly so)!

"no Makefile found" means... well.. that Make didn't even see the makefile.  The suggestions to rename the Makefile.m to Makefile are correct.   As well, the whole tab vs. whitespace thing is certainly pertinent.

Comment: Hi, the make command in the directory where makefile is and its name is Makefile with M. however what`s "tabs" ?

Comment: i tried to remove whitespaces, i got always the same output error :(

Comment: @Malek: And make sure your editor is set to use “real tabs” or “hard tabs”, not spaces. If you're using a Cocoa-based editor such as Xcode, press ctrl-q, then tab to always insert a real tab.

Comment: In emacs you can run M-x tabify

Comment: i deleted the spaces and replaced it by tabs but the same error, i do not know what to do :(

Comment: i tried "make all" command and it said: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop

Comment: Bad whitespace would *not* cause "No targets specified and no makefile found".

Comment: @Beta Herp-d-derp.  You are entirely correct and a bunch of us were jumping to problems beyond that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> and no makefile found

If you just type `make` with no arguments or `make all`, `make` will look for a file called `Makefile` in the current directory.  If it's not there, you get the error you saw.  `make` will not look in subdirectories for `Makefile` nor will it accept a file called `Makefile.m`.

Comment: Malek has not specified the version of Make, but GNUMake looks for 'GNUmakefile', then 'makefile', finally 'Makefile'.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the my makefile had the name MakeFile, changing it to Makefile worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Re:
$ Make
Make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I just had this error and found that the Makefile extension (none) had been converted to .bat somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

Just spent a few insanely frustrating moments with this error. My mistake was not all that subtle: I titled the makefile MakeFile not Makefile, so even using the -f Makefile command (forcing the makefile name) still resulted in not-found, because it was MakeFile, not Makefile.