# make *** no targets specified and no makefile found. stop

Tags: makefile

I have a problem installing package `dionaea`.

After I type this:

```
./configure --with-lcfg-include=/opt/dionaea/include/ \
--with-lcfg-lib=/opt/dionaea/lib/ \
--with-python=/opt/dionaea/bin/python3.1 \
--with-cython-dir=/usr/bin \
--with-udns-include=/opt/dionaea/include/ \
--with-udns-lib=/opt/dionaea/lib/ \
--with-emu-include=/opt/dionaea/include/ \
--with-emu-lib=/opt/dionaea/lib/ \
--with-gc-include=/usr/include/gc \
--with-ev-include=/opt/dionaea/include \
--with-ev-lib=/opt/dionaea/lib \
--with-nl-include=/opt/dionaea/include \
--with-nl-lib=/opt/dionaea/lib/ \
--with-curl-config=/opt/dionaea/bin/ \
--with-pcap-include=/opt/dionaea/include \
--with-pcap-lib=/opt/dionaea/lib/ \
--with-glib=/opt/dionaea
```

and the next step is:

```
#make
```

An error message appears:
`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.`

My directory is `/usr/local/src`

Comment: git clone git://git.carnivore.it/dionaea.git dionaea

Comment: Hi Blender, do you know how to solve it?
I really need help..

Comment: Your source should not be directly in `/usr/local/src`  You ought to have the dionaea source in a subdirectory.  If you do, you will have to run make in that subdirectory.

Comment: Okay..Thanks altendky for your help. I'll try it,
Because now i've used another method..~.~

Comment: Then you will need to configure the configuration file and start it.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you had mentioned the operating system you were working on. On my mac sometime I have this silly issue that the make command can not find `MakeFile` (with camel like capital letters) but recognizes the `makefile` or vice versa! the best is to look for either of the files in the current directory and run `make -f MakeFile` or `make -f makefile` ... and see if it works properly.

Comment: you should check `./configure`'s output log, I saw that my machine lack of `gcc`, so I `apt-get install gcc` and then `./configure` will generate the **makefile**.

Answer (score 41):

`make` takes a makefile as input. Makefile usually is named `makefile` or `Makefile`. The `configure` command should generate a makefile, so that `make` could be in turn executed. Check if a makefile has been generated under your working directory.

Comment: But before I've install some packet like libpcap,curl,sqlite and etc..
make can be execute.
Why when I want to install dionaea in different directory..it doesn't work?

Comment: How to check if a make file has been generated under my working directory?
Sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: Just "ls" to see if there is some file named makefile or Makefile.

Comment: Yes there are Makefile.am & Makefile.in
Then how to solve it? :)

Comment: Those are not makefile. They are input or material serving the configure command to generate makefile.

Comment: May i know how to create makefile under my working directory?

Comment: Your makefile should be created by the configure command. So maybe some problem with the configure command. You need to debug that.

Comment: A good `configure` command will be able to find all the libraries rather than requiring that you tell it each and every one.  Try running it just a `./configure`.  Also, look at the output of both runs for errors.

Comment: Yepp..Maybe that's a problem with my configure command.I'll double check it..

I've tried it before. Still error..Think will try again later..X_X

Thank you all ^^

Comment: FWIW, the OP's subject landed me here, and my unzipped directory tree wouldn't recognize `./configure` even with a `configure.ac` file and `Makefile.in` present -- SOLUTION --> I had to run `autoconf` first, **then** `./configure` and `make` were successful.

Comment: yes after "./configure" command there is an error  "configure: error: Cannot build a 32-bit program, you need to install 32-bit development libraries"                                                       What should I do next any suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

running `./configure` should solve your problem.

Comment: How will `make clean` work if there is no makefile?

Comment: `make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error and i fixed it by looking at the solution from this site:

http://trac.macports.org/ticket/40476.

SO did you got any error after running './configure' ? Maybe something about lacking tclConfig.sh. 
If so, instead of running './configure', you have to search for the **tclConfigure.sh** first and then put it in the command, in my case, its located in /usr/lib/. And then run: 
'**./configure ----with-tcl=/usr/lib --with-tclinclude=/usr/include**'

Answer (score 4):

`./configure` command should generate a makefile, named `makefile` or `Makefile`. if in the directory there is no this file, you should check whether the `configure` command execute success.

in my case, I configure the `apr-util`:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apr-util --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config
```

because the `--with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config`, the `apr` did not install yet, so there configure fail, there did not generate the `apr`'s `/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config`.

So I install the `apr`, then configure the `apr-util`, it works.

Answer (score 3):

You had to have something like this:

```
"configure: error: "Error: libcrypto required."
```

after your `./configure runs`. So you need to resolve noticed dependencies first and then try `./configure` once more time and then run make !

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this problem while trying to do a manual install of [texane's open-source STLink utility](https://github.com/texane/stlink) on Ubuntu. The solution was, oddly enough,

```sh
make clean
make
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, and found out that the makefile has to be named "makefile" or "Makefile" without a file name extention (.mk). Make doesn't find the file if the case is different on my system. (windows with mingw32-make)

Comment: Maybe this is not specific enough for the question, but this is the post that google shows if you search for the error message. Maybe it should link to another more general post?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If after ./configure Makefile.in and Makefile.am are generated and make fail (by showing this following make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.) so there is something not configured well, to solve it, first run "autoconf" commande to solve wrong configuration then re-run "./configure" commande and finally "make"

Answer (score 0):

Delete your source tree that was gunzipped or gzipped and extracted to folder and reextract again. Supply your options again

```
./configure --with-option=/path/etc ...
```

Then if all libs are present, your make should succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if there is any read and write permission denial to the user. Like  C:\Windows\System32\ have restricted access and you are cloned and trying to make from such restricted directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you create Makefile in the VSCode, your makefile doesnt run. I don't know the cause of this issue. Maybe the configuration of the file is not added to system. But I solved this way. delete created makefile, then go to project directory and right click mouse later create a file and named Makefile. After fill the Makefile and run it. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
make clean
./configure --with-option=/path/etc
make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a file Makefile.PL in a database library:
http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/DBI/DBI-1.630.tar.gz

The following command created the **makefile**

```
perl Makefile.PL
```

After that, **make** command worked

Comment: in which directory did you executed the make command that worked? did you used c or c++ yet?

Comment: Inside of DBI-1.630.tar.gz there is a file "Makefile.PL".  I use a basic linux shell with default perl installation

Comment: so you didn't understand the question, the questioner ask why makefile not found in dionaea package not for DBI. Do you know what makefile is?

Comment: question is related to a missing makefile. I try to help sharing my experience in which I i had the same problem but in another package. In my case `perl Makefile.PL` create the missing makefile

Comment: well dionaea is NOT perl, its python.

Comment: well makefile is **not related** to dionaea nor python. Makefile is required by a tool called **make** which is a default utility in linux. If any language(that depend on tools installed in s.o like python) throws an error **no makefile found** it means that in background is executing something related to **make** and its needs the classic makefile. On my case I had the same error, but with perl I could create the makefile from **Makefile.PL**

Comment: you didn't understand the conversation very well. Where did I mention that makefile is related to dionaea or python? I said, dionaea  IS NOT PERL, dionaea  is PYTHON. So. where is the relation of PERL Makefile.PL to dionaea  which is using PYTHON? did the questioner using PERL?

Comment: The question problem is related to missing makefile. Again, I showed my expierence because I was able to create the makefile using perl. Where did I mention that PERL is required for dionaea? Read about makefile and make tool to understand why you python app is wrong. MAYBE dionaea needs make tool or perl in a deep level that is not visible for simple users. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it can mean that ./configure command failed for some reason, in my case it was due to a missing package. So i have used my OS package manager to install required package (`autoconf` and `autoconf-archive` in my case), then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

first time try

```
make clean
make
```

if these didn't solve your issue you have to install build packages.

debian base

```
apt-get install build-essential libgtk-3-dev
```

For RHEL/CentOS

```
sudo yum install gcc glibc glibc-common gd gd-devel -y
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install the Required Dependencies

First, launch the Terminal and run the commands below to install the required dependencies and libraries.

`sudo apt install autoconf automake libpcre3-dev libnl-3-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev ethtool build-essential g++ libnl-genl-3-dev libgcrypt20-dev libtool python3-distutils`

`sudo apt install -y pkg-config`

Step 2: Compile and Install

Now, run the commands below (one by one in order) to compile the source code and install Your Repo on your system.
[Before this enter you directory ex: cd folder_name]

`sudo autoreconf -i`

`sudo ./configure --with-experimental --with-ext-scripts`

`sudo make`

`sudo make install`

I hope this time problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the output of the configure command.
Mine contained this error:

```
configure: error: in `/home/ubuntu/build/php-8.0.19':
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.
```

Then I googled the error and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Before running "make" you need to configure your build using "CMake"
Try:
cmake .

Answer (score 0):

Creating Makefile in the VScode did not worked for me. So, delete the make file created in the VS code, go to the project directory and create file add all the commands in it and name it as Makefile and save. Then try to execute it in VS code. It will work. Don't know why it doesn't work with VS code.

Answer (score 0):

Reg make all i know is
To run a make, Atleast one target must be preset in make file.

While running if target not specified, it will take first target present in make file.

Answer (score -1):

Unpack the source from a working directory and cd into the file directory as root. Use the commands ./configure then make and make install

Comment: I dislike the suggestion to run configure and make as root. Also, the OP says this is what he is doing: he ran configure but it didn't result in the creation of a Makefile.