# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, makefile

This question look duplicate to [make *** no targets specified and no makefile found. stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412919/make-no-targets-specified-and-no-makefile-found-stop) but my problem is slightly different and I tried that solution also but not work for me.
I'm working on OpenCV library and I start with sample project but this gives the following error to me. Please help me to solve this error.

```
17:31:25 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project MyFirstOpenCVJNI ****
make 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

17:31:25 Build Finished (took 122ms)
```

following is my Android.mk file
//Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

include ../includeOpenCV.mk
include $(OPENCV_MK_PATH)

LOCAL_MODULE    := first-opencvjni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := first-opencvjni.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: @blackbelt: see my updated post I add Android.mk file code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After many searches I solved the error,
 `right click on project->Properties->C/C++ Build(left side)->Builder Settings->uncheck the "Use default build command" checkbox->enter "${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd" in Build command checkbox` on windows OS, see the following image  [image]

before doing all thing you need to set the NDKROOT Environment variable in Environment settings to the root folder to your ndk directory in my case it is C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\android-ndk-r8e.
If any difficulties or queries let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`make` by default will execute file named `makefile` or `Makefile` in your case the `makefile` name is `Android.mk` so instead of executing make as `$~ make` execute it as

`$~ make -f Android.mk`

even i would like to know who is executing the `makefile`? Are you manually executing or its written in some script? If written in script try to change the `make` command to `make -f Android.mk` else if you can't change the script ( May be because of some reasons ) then rename your  `Android.mk` to `makefile` and check it.

Comment: I dont know who is executing the file makefile?, I'm beginer to OpenCV and I recently started learning the OpenCV library.

Comment: is Android.mk is generating on buildtime?

Comment: I change the build command to ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd  and the new error occure as make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/first-opencvjni/first-opencvjni.o] Error 1

Comment: Can you tel the steps u followed from beginning so that i can try on my pc and help u

Comment: I followed the http://docs.opencv.org/opencv_tutorials.pdf tutorial from page no. 57(1.8
Introduction into Android Development)