# Imagemagick install from source - No makefile found

Tags: makefile, ansible

I'm trying to install ImageMagick from source. To do this I'm using the instructions [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php). It works until the `make` command is executed. It says that it can't find the makefile `"cmd": "/usr/bin/make", "msg": "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."` I tried different targets such as 'all' and 'install', and no target. In the directory are 2 files `Makefile.am`, and `Makefile.in`.

This is the text from the Ansible playbook I set up for this:

```
- name: register directory name var
  shell: ls -d /path/ImageMagick-*
  register: dir_path

- name: configure imagemagick make
  command: "{{ dir_path.stdout }}/configure"

- name: Build default target
  make:
    chdir: "{{ dir_path.stdout }}"

- name: Run 'install' target
  make:
    chdir: "{{ dir_path.stdout }}"
    target: install
```

The problem seems to be in the `configure` step but it appears to have completed successfully, or else it should have displayed an error message, I suppose? Here is the output from Ansible as a paste: https://pastebin.com/MJjnQeRB

If I run `./configure` and then `make` on the command line, it works. So this seems to be an Ansible problem. How can I make it work?

Comment: What does the `configure` step end up doing? It should create your `Makefile` if it completes correctly.

Comment: It seemed to complete successfully ""ImageMagick 7.0.8-66 is configured as follows. Please verify that this", "configuration matches your expectations."

Comment: Your expectations should include "a Makefile was created" like it says in the comments in the  `configure` script itself. If it didn't do that, that's the part you need to troubleshoot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make \*\*\* no targets specified and no makefile found. stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412919/make-no-targets-specified-and-no-makefile-found-stop)

Comment: This is the output of creating makefile from config "config.status: creating Makefile", "config.status: creating magick.sh", "config.status: creating PerlMagick/check.sh", "config.status: creating PerlMagick/default/Magick.pm", "config.status: creating PerlMagick/Makefile.PL",

Comment: thanks, I've been reading through those answers. There's no Makefile, so it might be due to some unmet dependency. The config file has some output like this -  "checking for library containing socket... none required". I'm guessing this means it's not finding it, but it's required.

Comment: You really need to [edit] the question to provide the actual output from `configure`, probably pared down to a useful subset. The answer to the `make` part is already provided in the proposed duplicate. I'm afraid there is no simple way to tell you exactly what to look for in the `configure` output.

Comment: The usual, simple solution to "how do I install ImageMagick" is "use your distro's package manager" unless you specifically require to build from source because you want to make changes to the sources before buidling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199995/discussion-between-matts-and-tripleee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your other targets use `chdir` to switch to another directory, but you're not doing that for `configure`, so its output lands somewhere else.  You need to run `configure` and `make` in the same directory.

Option 1: add `chdir:` to the `configure` recipe, too.

Option 2: remove `chdir:` from the other recipes.

Option 3: collapse `configure` and `make` to run in the same recipe, and `chdir:` or not as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, I used option 1, and edited question with command that worked.

Comment: Your question should generally remain strictly a question; feel free to post an answer of your own, and even accept that if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the command to include chdir:

```
- name: configure imagemagick make
  command: ./configure
  args:
    chdir: "{{ dir_path.stdout }}"
```