# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop after ./configure in Dogecoin?

Tags: macos, bitcoin, apple-m1

I have try to run the Dogecoin in Mac using terminal,
I have successfully done some steps,

https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md

currently the make command not working it found some issues.

> configure: error: Found Berkeley DB other than 5.1, required for portable wallets (--with-incompatible-bdb to ignore or --disable-wallet to disable wallet functionality)

```
dogecoin % make
```

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I have try this solution but it's not fixed:

[make *** no targets specified and no makefile found. stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412919/make-no-targets-specified-and-no-makefile-found-stop)

Please tell me of any solution.

Comment: Please put your code as text, not a link.

Answer (score 0):

The configure command fails and does not build `Makefile`, so `make` cannot find any target.

The problem is clearly described in `configure` command error message.

> configure: error: Found Berkeley DB other than 5.1, required for portable wallets (--with-incompatible-bdb to ignore or --disable-wallet to disable wallet functionality)

To fix this you can install Berkeley DB v. 5.1 or provide one of the recommended opttions to configure.

`--with-incompatible-bdb`
or
`--disable-wallet`