# MakeFile is not found when I call make

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile

I have a small C program that just computes Fibonacci. I have make file to build the file, and when I call make, I get the message `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`. If I call make clean, I get `` make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop. `` but it seems to see a makeFile (I think). I'm pretty lost and need help.

Here's the text of the make file:

```
CC=gcc

all: fibonacci

fibonacci: fibonacci.c 
    $(CC) -pthread -o fib.exe

clean: 
    rm fib.e xe
```

Comment: What is the filename of your make file?

Comment: the file is called MakeFile

Comment: use `Makefile`, literally

Comment: It's case-sensitive and should be `Makefile`.

Comment: The errors you posted do not prove existence of a `Makefile`. You will get the same error messages even when `Makefile` is missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No targets specified and no makefile found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962460/no-targets-specified-and-no-makefile-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename your makefile to `Makefile` or use `make -f <whatever_name_you_like>`. Remember that in unix-like systems file names are often case-sensitive (not in all types of filesystems but in many)

Answer (score 2):

Refer this answer  [No targets specified and no makefile found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962460/no-targets-specified-and-no-makefile-found)

By default, when make looks for the makefile, it tries the following names, in order: GNUmakefile, makefile and Makefile.

You can also try `make all` and read

[What Name to Give Your Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Names.html)